# How to cross validate RandomForest model?

Tags: apache-spark, random-forest, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-mllib

I want to evaluate a random forest being trained on some data. Is there any utility in Apache Spark to do the same or do I have to perform cross validation manually?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

ML provides [`CrossValidator`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator) class which can be used to perform cross-validation and parameter search. Assuming your data is already preprocessed you can add cross-validation as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

// [label: double, features: vector]
trainingData org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = ??? 
val nFolds: Int = ???
val numTrees: Int = ???
val metric: String = ???

val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setNumTrees(numTrees)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(rf)) 

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().build() // No parameter search

val evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
  // "f1" (default), "weightedPrecision", "weightedRecall", "accuracy"
  .setMetricName(metric) 

val cv = new CrossValidator()
  // ml.Pipeline with ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  // ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
  .setEvaluator(evaluator) 
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(nFolds)

val model = cv.fit(trainingData) // trainingData: DataFrame
```

Using PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

trainingData = ... # DataFrame[label: double, features: vector]
numFolds = ... # Integer

rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features")
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator() # + other params as in Scala    

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[rf])
paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder. 
    .addGrid(rf.numTrees, [3, 10])
    .addGrid(...)  # Add other parameters
    .build())

crossval = CrossValidator(
    estimator=pipeline,
    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
    evaluator=evaluator,
    numFolds=numFolds)

model = crossval.fit(trainingData)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works for leave-one-out? The kFold() call under the hood doesn't appear to deterministically return two folds length N-1 and 1. When I run the code above with a RegressionEvaluator and Lasso model I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Nothing has been added to this summarizer.

Comment: No, I am pretty sure it doesn't. `MLUtils.kFold` is using `BernoulliCellSampler` to determine split. From the other hand cost of performing  leave-one-out cross-validation in Spark is probably to high anyway to be make it feasible in practice.

Comment: Hello @zero323, when you set a metric in your Evaluator object like .setMetricName("precision") . My question is, how can I get those metric calulated during training process? (Please refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778532/how-to-get-precision-recall-using-crossvalidator-for-training-naivebayes-model-u)

Comment: Hey @zero323 ,  is there a need to split data into training/testing when using cross validation? As CV trains and test over a number of folds, it should then give an accuracy of the average of the accuracy training/testing on the five folds? Or maybe I am way off.

Comment: @other15 Personally I would choose independent out-of-sample confirmation with CV as well. For obvious reason you can omit validation set though.

Comment: AFAICT, you don't have access to the test metric on the test set, only the training set (for the best model).

Comment: @zero323 I think you should change "precision" with "accuracy", according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15771

Comment: @user299791 Thanks. Let's make it generic.

Comment: @zero323 I would actually being able to understand better MulticlassClassificationEvaluator results, but it seems like there is not much examples around

Answer (score 2):

To build on zero323's great answer using Random Forest Classifier, here is a similar example for Random Forest Regressor:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor // CHANGED
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator // CHANGED
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{VectorAssembler, VectorIndexer}

val numFolds = ??? // Integer
val data = ??? // DataFrame

// Training (80%) and test data (20%)
val Array(train, test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.8,0.2))
val featuresCols = data.columns
val va = new VectorAssembler()
va.setInputCols(featuresCols)
va.setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
val vi = new VectorIndexer()
vi.setInputCol("rawFeatures")
vi.setOutputCol("features")
vi.setMaxCategories(5)
val regressor = new RandomForestRegressor()
regressor.setLabelCol("events")

val metric = "rmse"
val evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator()
  .setLabelCol("events")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
  //     "rmse" (default): root mean squared error
  //     "mse": mean squared error
  //     "r2": R2 metric
  //     "mae": mean absolute error 
  .setMetricName(metric) 

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().build()
val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(regressor)
  .setEvaluator(evaluator) 
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(numFolds)

val model = cv.fit(train) // train: DataFrame
val predictions = model.transform(test)
predictions.show
val rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println(rmse)
```

Evaluator metric source: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator