# How to get Precision/Recall using CrossValidator for training NaiveBayes Model using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-1.5

Supossed I have a Pipeline like this:

```
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("tweet").setOutputCol("words")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF().setNumFeatures(1000).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features")
val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("idffeatures")
val nb = new org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes()
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, nb))
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(hashingTF.numFeatures, Array(10, 100, 1000)).addGrid(nb.smoothing, Array(0.01, 0.1, 1)).build()
val cv = new CrossValidator().setEstimator(pipeline).setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()).setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid).setNumFolds(10)
val cvModel = cv.fit(df)
```

As you can see I defined a CrossValidator using a MultiClassClassificationEvaluator. I have seen a lot of examples getting metrics like Precision/Recall during testing process but these metris are gotten when you use a different set of data for testing purposes (See for example this [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#binary-classification)).

From my understanding, CrossValidator is going to create folds and one fold will be use for testing purposes, then CrossValidator will choose the best model. My question is, is possible to get Precision/Recall metrics during training process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the only metric which is actually stored is the one you define when you create an instance of an `Evaluator`. For the `BinaryClassificationEvaluator` this can take one of the two values:

- `areaUnderROC`
- `areaUnderPR`

with the former one being default, and can be set using `setMetricName` method.

These values are collected during training process and can accessed using `CrossValidatorModel.avgMetrics`. Order of values corresponds to the order of `EstimatorParamMaps` (`CrossValidatorModel.getEstimatorParamMaps`).

Comment: @zero233 I don't seem to find the avgMetrics and other attributes in my spark . 

cvModel.avgMetrics
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-d454795422c1> in <module>()
----> 1 cvModel.avgMetrics

AttributeError: 'CrossValidatorModel' object has no attribute 'avgMetrics'